# Passing a function template as an argument without specifying template type

Tags: c++, templates, variant

Right now I have this:

```
template<typename T>
static void equalize(Image<T>& image) {
    // implementation
}

...

// receive signal from GUI
void applyEqualize(int row) {
        auto variant = *images[row];

        if (std::holds_alternative<Image<ushort>>(variant)) {
            Image<ushort>& image = std::get<Image<ushort>>(variant);
            equalize<ushort>(image);
        }

        else if (std::holds_alternative<Image<float>>(variant)) {
            Image<float>& image = std::get<Image<float>>(variant);
            equalize<float>(image);
        }
}
    
...

private:
        std::vector<std::shared_ptr<std::variant<Image<ushort>, Image<float>>> images;
```

I would like to be able to call a wrapper function that takes a function template and performs the variant type checking and calls the function, but I can't figure out how to pass a function template without specifying the typename. Something like this:

```
template <template<class> class F>
void Wrapper(F&& f, int row)
{
        auto variant = *images[row];

        if (std::holds_alternative<Image<ushort>>(variant)) {
            Image<ushort>& image = std::get<Image<ushort>>(variant);
            f<ushort>(image);
        }

        else if (std::holds_alternative<Image<float>>(variant)) {
            Image<float>& image = std::get<Image<float>>(variant);
            f<float>(image);
        }
}
```

Then

```
Wrapper(equalize, row)
```

But it doesn't compile because the F&& f parameter is invalid without specifying the concrete type of the argument. How can I implement this behaviour?

Comment: Are you looking for `std::visit([](auto& image){ equalize(image); }, *images[row]);`?

Answer (score 6):

Standard library has you covered for this use case with [`std::visit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit), no need to write your own wrapper:

```
void applyEqualize(int row) {
    std::visit([this](auto& image){ equalize(image); }, *images[row]);
}
```

[See example online](https://godbolt.org/z/Khd6Y4Mr5)

Answer (score 1):

Change the function to a functor with templated `operator()`:

```
struct equalize {
    template<typename T>
    void operator() (Image<T>& image) {
        // implementation
    }
};

// no need to make the wrapper a function template
void Wrapper(equalizer& eq, int row) {
       // make use of template argument deduction
       f(image);
}
```

Now you can create instances and pass them to functions, before you need to bother to decide what `T` is. Only when you call the functor the member template gets instantiated.